# Why do I get an error message when I implemented a simple shell command on Linux?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, operating-system

In Linux Ubuntu 20.04.4, I implemented a simple shell command in the "sh.c" file.
Entering

```
./a.out
```

and command line by line runs normally.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPXCX.png)

```
ls > y
cat < y | sort | uniq | wc > y1
cat y1
rm y1
ls | sort | uniq | wc
rm y
```

However, if you save the commands to the "t.sh" file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsemg.png)
and run them at once like

```
./a.out < t.sh
```

an error appears.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27ecN.png)

print result :

```
5 5 29
5 5 29
cat: y1: No such file or directory
rm: Cannot erase 'y1': no such file or directory
4 4 27
rm: Cannot clear 'y': no such file or directory
```

When I checked with the "ls" command, both the cat and rm commands worked well, but I got a error message like that "rm: Cannot erase 'y1': no such file or directory."

What's the problem?
The other person worked normally with the same code...

This is part of the code implemented.

```
void runcmd(struct cmd *cmd)
{
  int p[2], r;
  int fd;
  int pid;
  char str[30] ="/bin/";
  FILE * stream;
  struct execcmd *ecmd;
  struct pipecmd *pcmd;
  struct redircmd *rcmd;

  if(cmd == 0)
    _exit(0);

  switch(cmd->type){
  default:
    fprintf(stderr, "unknown runcmd\n");
    _exit(-1);

  case ' ':
    ecmd = (struct execcmd*)cmd;
    if(ecmd->argv[0] == 0){
      _exit(0);
    fprintf(stderr, "exec not implemented\n");
    }
    // Your code here ...
    else if(execvp(ecmd->argv[0],ecmd->argv)==-1){
        ecmd->argv[0] = strcat(str,ecmd->argv[0]);
    
        if(execvp(ecmd->argv[0],ecmd->argv)==-1){       
            fprintf(stderr,"file not found\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        
    }
    break;

  case '>':
    rcmd = (struct redircmd*)cmd;
    ecmd = (struct execcmd*)(rcmd->cmd);
    if(0 <(fd = open(rcmd->file,O_CREAT|O_WRONLY,0644))){ 

        stream = freopen(rcmd->file,"w",stdout);
        runcmd(rcmd->cmd); 
        fclose(stream);
        }
    else {
            fprintf(stderr,"file open error\n");
        }
    close(fd);
    stream = NULL;  
    break;
  case '<':
    rcmd = (struct redircmd*)cmd;
    // Your code here ...
    if( 0 < (fd = open(rcmd->file,rcmd->flags))){
        stream = freopen(rcmd->file,"r",stdin);
        runcmd(rcmd->cmd);
        fclose(stream);
        close(fd);
    }
    else fprintf(stderr,"file open error\n");
    break;

  case '|':

    pcmd = (struct pipecmd*)cmd;
     // Your code here ...
    struct cmd * lcmd =(pcmd->left);
    struct cmd * rcmd =(pcmd->right);
    int fd[2];

    if(pipe(fd)==-1){ 
        fprintf(stderr,"pipe error");
        exit(1);
    }
    pid = fork1(); 

    if(pid == 0){ 
        dup2(fd[1],1); 
        close(fd[0]);  
        runcmd(lcmd); 
    }

    else{ 
        dup2(fd[0],0); 
        close(fd[1]); 
        runcmd(rcmd);
     }
    
    break;
  }    
   _exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared #!/bin/sh at top of script